# How to fit Graded Response Model with lme4::glmer

Tags: r, glmm, item-response-theory

Thanks to Rijmen et al.(2003), we can fit GRM to the data with `lme4::glmer`.

I think Rasch model is straightforward, with `data.frame` with columns like this

```
 response  person  item
 0         1      1
 0         1      2
 1         1      3
 ...
 1         2      1
 0         2      2
```

we can fit Rasch model like this

```
 glmer(response ~ -1 + item + (1|person), data=   , family="binomial")
```

But how about GRM? The data would be like this

```
 response  person  item
 2         1      1
 4         1      2
 3         1      3
 ...
 1         2      1
 4         2      2
 ...
```

For a Likert scale (1 to 5). I thought converting the data like this

```
 response  person item  category
 1          1    1       2
 0          1    1       3
 1          1    2       4
 0          1    2       5
```

Because for `person1`, `item1`, the response is 2, which means that for response 2, it's yes and for response 3, it's no.

The model would be

```
 response ~ item:category + (1|person)
```

But I am not quite sure this is the right way to do...

*Note*: person, item, category variables are all factors

According to [De Boeck et al. (2011)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i12/paper), GRM cannot be fitted with `lmer`
which is rather in contrast to Rijmen et al(2003).

=== ADDED

Now I think I am pretty sure it will work, at least for GRM with no slope parameter.

Data should be coded like this.

```
response  person item  category
 0          1    1       1
 1          1    1       2
 1          1    1       3
 1          1    1       4
 1          1    1       5  (which is always true so should be omitted.)
```

for 1-5 category(ordinal) answer.

Main benefit of using GLMM for IRT model is you can put other covariates
(person, item, person-item) into the model.

And for GRM, you can set the difference between the ordinal response is the same,
which can't be handled by ordinary GRM function, for example, ltm::grm.
(Oh, I see ordinal::clmm can handle this, but I doubt it can be useful for a model like this)

```
  response ~ item + (1 + category|person)
```

or this

```
  response ~ item + (-1 + category|item) + (1|person)
```

in this case, category is integer and would be better if coded as -2, -1, 0, 1, 2.

**References**

Rijmen, F., Tuerlinckx, F., De Boeck, P., & Kuppens, P. (2003). A nonlinear mixed model framework for item response theory. Psychological methods, 8(2), 185.

De Boeck, P., Bakker, M., Zwitser, R., Nivard, M., Hofman, A., Tuerlinckx, F., & Partchev, I. (2011). The estimation of item response models with the lmer function from the lme4 package in R. Journal of Statistical Software, 39(12), 1-28.

====

Here's my source.

```
library(ltm)
#Science[c(1,3,4,7)]
Sci.df <- Science[c(1,3,4,7)] # Comfort, Work, Future, Benefit
Sci.df$id = 1:nrow(Sci.df)

Sci.long <- reshape(Sci.df, varying=colnames(Sci.df[-5]), 
                v.names="Response", timevar="item", idvar=c("id"), direction="long")
Sci.long$id <- as.factor(Sci.long$id)
Sci.long$item <- as.factor(Sci.long$item)

library(ordinal)
Sci.long.clmm <- clmm(Response ~ (1|id)+item, data=Sci.long, threshold="flexible",     nAGQ=-21)
summary(Sci.long.clmm)

Positive1=as.integer(Sci.long$Response)<=1
    Positive2=as.integer(Sci.long$Response)<=2
Positive3=as.integer(Sci.long$Response)<=3

Sci.long.sep1=Sci.long
Sci.long.sep1$Response=1; Sci.long.sep1$Positive=Positive1

Sci.long.sep2=Sci.long
Sci.long.sep2$Response=2; Sci.long.sep2$Positive=Positive2

Sci.long.sep3=Sci.long
Sci.long.sep3$Response=3; Sci.long.sep3$Positive=Positive3

Sci.long.sep = rbind(Sci.long.sep1, Sci.long.sep2, Sci.long.sep3)

Sci.long.sep$Response=as.factor(Sci.long.sep$Response)

Sci.long.sep.glmm <- glmer(Positive ~ -1 + Response + item + (1|id), data=Sci.long.sep, family=binomial,
                       nAGQ=21, control=glmerControl(optimizer="optimx",
                       optCtrl=list(method="nlminb"), check.conv.grad= .makeCC("warning", tol = 1e-4, relTol = NULL) ))
summary(Sci.long.sep.glmm)
```

I tried my best to make it same for clmm and glmer... but the log likelihood is different.

logLik = -1730.6 for glmer
logLik = -1633.5 for clmm

and the parameters r not the same but similar.

Does anyone know why the log likehoods are different?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't fit GRM in glmer, as the gl stands for generalized linear and the GRM is a generalized nonlinear model. This means the structural part of the model is not a linear predictor but is of the form $a*(b+c)$ with $a,b,c$ unknown. Linear would be something like $b+c$ (e.g., a Rasch model). I therefore agree with de Boeck.

Comment: 1st comment: As far as I know, Rijmen et al. *do not* say that one can fit a GRM using `lme4::glmer()`, and indeed I don't see how one could--please provide a page reference in Rijmen et al. if you disagree. 2nd comment: I *think* you can fit GRM in `ordinal::clmm()`, although I haven't personally looked into it closely. 3rd comment: I don't know what your actual question is. Please edit your question to very clearly state what it is you want to know or are confused about.

Comment: @Momo, I guess you're right. Sorry for not mentioning. I thought of GRM with constrained slope parameter.

Comment: @Jake Westfall, As far as I figure, he is alluding that Polytomous Data can be modeled by GLMM(Generalized Linear Mixed Model, I am not referring to any particular package here). See page 191 of Rijmen et al.(2003) $L_{nij}=x_{nij} beta + z'_{nij} theta _n$ So everything's fine here. Link function and linear predictors

Comment: @Jake Westfall, I guess I am wrong about the way of implementing my data. For each category, the code should be 0 and 1 and the only category the subject selected should be 1. and the logit function should be different, that is cumulative logit function. So I guess I have to redefine link function...???

Comment: @Jake Westfall, Rijmen et al.(2003) says, "The mixed logistic regression model can handle polytomous responses by ..." and I thought mixed logistic regression model can be covered by GLMM...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be curious about the same thing,
clmm can fit GRM with slope 1... but I don't think clmm can allow different slopes for different items.

Here's the code.

```
library(ltm) # For data Science
library(ordinal)

# Science to Long format
head(ltm::Science)

Sci <- ltm::Science; 
Sci$id <- 1:nrow(Sci)
    Sci.long <- reshape(Sci, varying = list(1:7), v.names = "resp", idvar="id",     direction="long",
                        timevar="item")
    Sci.long$item <- factor(Sci.long$item, labels=colnames(ltm::Science))
head(Sci.long)

Sci.clmm <- clmm(resp ~ item + (1|id), data = Sci.long, link = "logit", threshold = "flexible",
                 nAGQ=-31,
                 control = list(method = "nlminb", trace = 1,  # trace : 1=outer op, -1=inner op.
                              maxIter = 1000, gradTol = 1e-5, maxLineIter = 1000,  useMatrix = FALSE,
                              innerCtrl = "giveError"))

Sci.clmm2 <- clmm2(location = resp ~ item , data = Sci.long, random = factor(id), link = "logistic", threshold = "flexible",
                 nAGQ=-31,                 
                 control = clmm2.control(method = "nlminb", trace = 1,  # trace : 1=outer op, -1=inner op.
                                maxIter = 1000, gradTol = 1e-5, maxLineIter = 1000))

library(mirt)


model = "F1 = 1 - 7
COV = F1 * F1
START = (1-7, a1, 1)
FIXED = (1-7, a1)
CONSTRAIN = (1-7, d1), (1-7, d2), (1-7, d3)
"
#as.numeric(as.character(ltm::Science))

Science2 <- sapply(ltm::Science, as.numeric)

Sci.mirt <- mirt(Science2, mirt.model(model), itemtype="grsm", TOL=1e-5, quadpts = 31)

# COMPARE The Result from mirt and clmm/clmm2
coef(Sci.mirt)
Sci.clmm
Sci.clmm2
```

So the results are identical, one thing to give heed to is that mixed model allows free random effect variance, but IRT model assumes variance of theta = 1.

```
> coef(Sci.mirt)
$Comfort
    a1    d1    d2     d3 c
par  1 3.642 1.642 -0.888 0

$Environment
        a1    d1    d2     d3      c
    par  1 3.642 1.642 -0.888 -0.292
    ...
    $GroupPars
    MEAN_1 COV_11
par      0  0.679

> Sci.clmm
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Gauss-Hermite 
quadrature approximation with 31 quadrature points 

formula: resp ~ item + (1 | id)
data:    Sci.long

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter   max.grad
 logit flexible  2744 -3072.83 6165.66 1119(3) 1.04e-03

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.6788   0.8239  
Number of groups:  id 392 

Coefficients:
itemEnvironment        itemWork      itemFuture  itemTechnology            itemIndustry     itemBenefit 
        -0.2922         -0.9476         -0.2901         -0.2036          0.4632         -0.6788 

Thresholds:
strongly disagree|disagree             disagree|agree       agree|strongly     agree 
                   -3.6419                    -1.6420                         0.8886 
> Sci.clmm2
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Gauss-Hermite 
quadrature approximation with 31 quadrature points 

Call:
clmm2(location = resp ~ item, random = factor(id), data = Sci.long, 
    link = "logistic", control = clmm2.control(method = "nlminb", 
        trace = 1, maxIter = 1000, gradTol = 1e-05, maxLineIter = 1000), 
    nAGQ = -31, threshold = "flexible")

Random effects:
                 Var   Std.Dev
factor(id) 0.6788056 0.8238966

Location coefficients:
itemEnvironment        itemWork      itemFuture  itemTechnology        itemIndustry     itemBenefit 
     -0.2922101      -0.9476163      -0.2901400      -0.2035440           0.4631815      -0.6788248 

No Scale coefficients

Threshold coefficients:
strongly disagree|disagree             disagree|agree       agree|strongly agree 
                -3.6419330                 -1.6420389                      0.8885574 

log-likelihood: -3072.828 
AIC: 6165.656
```

And one way to use glmer to fit GRM is mention as
"An approximate ML estimation method for CLMs" in 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_intro.pdf